# push navigation is not working on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, navigationbar

I am using a basic navigation menu on my website, which displays the menu icon and reveals the navigation bar only when clicked on it. The code works great on desktop and certain mobile devices (iPhone 6, Samsung Tab 3), but it does not display properly on the iPhone 4, Samsung Galaxy S4 and even on iPad Air.

The menu icon is not being pushed right when clicked on. It remains where it is, though the same code allows the icon to shift places on desktop view. I cannot figure out where the problem is. I suspected the media queries but after deleting the media query the problem still persists. The only workaround I managed to come up with is by increasing the top padding of the first item of the navigation. But this is not ideal.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Below you will find the html and css code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $menuLeft = $('.pushmenu-left');
  $nav_list = $('#nav_list');

  $nav_list.click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.pushmenu-push').toggleClass('pushmenu-push-toright');
    $menuLeft.toggleClass('pushmenu-open');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  width: 100% height: auto;
  margin-top: -6.25em;
  position: relative;
}
.pushmenu {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  width: 120px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 1em;
}
.pushmenu a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 14px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.pushmenu a:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.pushmenu a:active {
  color: #bdbdbd;
}
.pushmenu-left {
  left: -120px;
}
.pushmenu-left.pushmenu-open {
  left: 0;
}
.pushmenu-push {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
.pushmenu-push-toright {
  left: 120px;
}
.pushmenu .pushmenu-push {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
#nav_list {
  background: url(hamburger-menu-icon.svg) no-repeat left top;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 27px;
  width: 33px;
  text-indent: -9999em;
}
nav-list.active {
  background-position: -33px top;
}
.buttonset {
  height: 16px;
  padding: 10px 20px 20px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
@media all and (min-width: 260px) and (max-width: 442px) {
  .pushmenu {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  .pushmenu a {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  .pushmenu a:first-child {
    padding-top: 40px;
  }
  .pushmenu-left {
    left: -200px;
  }
  .pushmenu-push-toright {
    left: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
</head>

<body class="pushmenu-push">
  <header>
    <nav class="pushmenu pushmenu-left">
      <a href="i.html">HOME</a>
      <a href="a.html">ABOUT</a>
      <a href="s.html">SERVICES</a>
      <a href="c.html">CONTACT</a>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="main">
        <section class="buttonset">
          <div id="nav_list">Menu</div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>


</body>

</html>
```

** EDIT:

[nav bar closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSWVm.png)
[active nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo66d.png)

Comment: From the code you provided, there is nothing that can suggest what happens. Please create a full working example that shows the problem. Also, you close the `</html>` tag, but it never opens.

Comment: Yeah this doesn't seem to "work great". Fix your snippet so that it can actually run.

Comment: Sorry for that. The reason why the code might not be showing anything is because the hamburger icon I use in the code is a SVG image which you would need in order to see it when the code is executed. I am adding two screenshots to the above post.